# Update a table using ArrayList by making a single DB call

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to update multiple rows in a table based on the `ArrayList<>` below in a single DB call using Spring JPA.

`CREATE TABLE phoneStatus (Status VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, Phone VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)`

```
[
    {
        "status": "Green",
        "phone": "2099028090"
    },
    {
        "status": "Red",
        "phone": "3099036070"
    }
]
```

Method Query - `UPDATE phoneStatus SET status=?1 WHERE phone=?2`

Operation - `list.foreach(object -> repo.method(x.getStatus(), x.getPhone());`

This is causing performance lag due to multiple DB updates(~150).

**PS**: Please correct my wording/question if I've made a mistake.

#### EDIT

For those of you asking how the transaction is posted to DB, below is the Spring JPA callout.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE phoneStatus SET status=?1 WHERE phone=?2", nativeQuery = true)
void updatePhoneStatus(String status, String phone);
```

Comment: I suggest [batch update](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s04.html)

Comment: How are you aquiring connection? Are you trying to update stateless(one conn for each update. e.g. jdbcTemplate.execute)? That seems like the obvious bottleneck. 150 updates seems quite less. Batch update is the right solution.

Comment: are you using any ORM  tool?

Comment: Another option can be to use Stored Procedures with table type input. Stored Procedures can be called from your Datasource object

Comment: @EspringDev yea Stored Procedures is an option that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using spring-data-jpa? Try setting the batch_size property to something reasonable. There are other batch-related configs you can find, better documentation on than I can write here.

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10`